# Why does $t^{i\lambda}=\cos(\lambda \ln(t))+\sin(\lambda \ln(t))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My equation was
$$tf''(t)+f'(t)+\frac{\lambda^2}{t}f(t)=0$$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. I set $f(t)=t^{m+1}$ and solve from there to obtain $m=\pm i\lambda$. The general solution then is $$f(t)=c_1 \cos(\lambda \ln(t)) + c_2 \sin(\lambda \ln(t))$$
which I obtained via a table in the my book for Euler-Cauchy method.

Can anyone tell me why $t^{i\lambda}=\cos(\lambda \ln(t)) + i \sin(\lambda \ln(t))$? I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours, and it has been awfully unsuccessful. :(

Comment: For $t > 0$, $t^{i\lambda} = e^{i\lambda \ln t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, for $t>0$, $t^{i\lambda}=e^{i(\lambda\ln{t})}=\cos{(\lambda\ln{t})}+i\sin{(\lambda\ln{t})}$

Comment: Oh my. Goes to show how easily I can overcomplicate things. I was trying to do this with infinite series...